# How to persist package identifier in FedEx Ship API?

Tags: c#, api, fedex

Using the FedEx Ship API, I'd like to attach a reference number to a `RequestedPackageLineItem` and have it returned in the matching `CompletedPackageDetail` element. But I see no option to do this. The only workaround I see is to split the shipment per-package and use `ProcessShipmentRequest.TransactionDetail.CustomerTransactionId` property instead. But it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to do it this way.